# biblatex: removing :eng from fullcite

Tags: biblatex

I am writing an annotated bibliography, using the command `\fullcite{key}` to list the reference.

How can I get biblatex to suppress the language entry? ie it produces

> Author,A.  (2010) Title. eng. Journal, etc.

I have tried issuing the command `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{language}}`
and it works for entries if I do a `\printbibliography` command, but not for anything produced by `\fullcite{key}`.

Can anyone help me with this? At the moment, digging into the sourcode for biblatex to make a modified `\fullcite` command looks a bit difficult for me.,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

The command `\AtEveryBibitem` that you're using does not affect `\fullcite`. If you want to make adjustments to the `\fullcite` results, you can use `\AtEveryCitekey` in place of `\AtEveryBibitem`.

If you want the same adjustments for both `\printbibliography` and `\fullcite`, you can make your adjustements with `\AtEveryBibitem`, then use:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\UseBibitemHook}
```

(Version 2.7 or later of biblatex needed for `\UseBibitemHook`.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to modify the definition of `\fullcite` (`language` is of type `list`, so one has to use `\clearlist` instead of `\clearfield`)

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\clearlist{language}\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```